# If I could lock a few tables, would it be bad?

Tags: php, mysql

Let's create Page.php

```
 query1
 query2
 query3
```

Is there any way to lock a few tables, so if one user visits Page.php and second user opens this page a little bit later, second user would need to wait until the first user's all queries executes.

And more importantly, would it slow a website very much if there are a few hundreds users on the same page at the same time?

Thank you.

Comment: Why would you want to lock tables for a simple query?

Comment: @wallyk : it can't happen at the same time.

Comment: Don't lock.  Use transactions.

Comment: seems like a bad idea, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I think it can happen at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use row level locking to cause the connection to block for other users.

```
BEGIN TRAN

UPDATE table1 set locked = 1;  //table locks are only taken out when data is written, you could possibly also use lock hints.
UPDATE table2 set locked = 1;
UPDATE table3 set locked = 1;

//Tables are locked, do whatever you need here, other users hitting the page will block at the first update statement until this connection hits the commit or rollback

update table1 set locked = 0;
update table2 set locked = 0;
update table3 set locked = 0;

COMMIT
```

Note that a select statement never causes a lock on a row or table though you may be able to use locking hints to cause it to lock the row.  Your best bet is to just touch the row by setting a value in the row to itself or adding another column.

Databases perform well because they accommodate concurrency.  Any time you cause what would be concurrent to behave serially, you'll incur a performance penalty.  In some cases this may be okay, it really depends on what you're actually doing with it.

I'm more of a SQL Server guy, but it's pretty generic DBMS concepts, for further information I would look into:

Transaction Isolation Levels
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/set-transaction.html

Locking Hints
http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/08/05/how-to-give-locking-hints-in-mysql/

Row / Table Locking Mechanisms
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/internal-locking.html

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to lock a few tables

You could do that using [lock tables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/lock-tables.html), but it would slow your page down

> And more importantly, would it slow a
>   website very much if there are a few
>   hundreds users on the same page at the
>   same time?

It wil slow down your page if you do it that way.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/lock-tables-restrictions.html:

> You can also avoid locking tables in
>   some cases by using the user-level
>   advisory lock functions [GET_LOCK()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_get-lock) and
>   RELEASE_LOCK(). These locks are saved
>   in a hash table in the server and
>   implemented with [pthread_mutex_lock()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_release-lock)
>   and pthread_mutex_unlock() for high
>   speed. See Section 11.14,
>   “Miscellaneous Functions”.

I still think like other people are telling you should just use [transactions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html) instead.

---

P.S: What are you trying to achieve I bet there is a better way to achieve this. Probably even without locks/transactions.