# Is there a way to get the inserted indentities in views?

Tags: sql, sql-server

So suppose we a table `t1` and we need to copy every inserted row into `t2` and put the foreign key link between them. Let me show what I mean:

We have table t1

```
-----------------------------
| id |  value  | external_id|
-----------------------------
|    |         |            |
-----------------------------
```

and table t2

```
----------------
| id |  value  |
----------------
|    |         |
----------------
```

where id columns have IDENTITY mark and external_id is a link to t2.id (I'll explain below)

We are going to insert row (value = 'TEST') into table t1. The expected result is something like this:

```
-----------------------------
| id |  value  | external_id|
-----------------------------
| 123| TEST    | 345        |
-----------------------------
```

and table t2

```
----------------
| id | value   |
----------------
| 345| TEST    |
----------------
```

The main idea of algorythm is based on triggers: in `INSTEAD OF` trigger on table1 I do:

1. insert into t1 and remember the inserted id's in a separate table using `OUTPUT` clause
2. insert into t2 and remember the mapping `(t1.id, t2.id)` again with `OUTPUT`
3. update `external_id` column using the mapping

But there are some issues which I cannot figure how to fight with:

1. t1 is not a table actually, it's a view with `INSTEAD OF` trigger (but that's not a problem)
2. t2 is also a view with a trigger an that's a problem because I cannot get the inserted id's from it
3. moreover t2 is a remote view - and that's a big problem because there some restrictions in using remote views

So. Maybe I was moving in a wrong direction? Is there a way to solve my problem without using cursors and stored procedure in a trigger on t1? (I mean I know there's a way to put all my data into t2 with a stored procedure and get the inserted id's in OUTPUT parameter of that procedure but maybe there's more elegant way?)

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that if t1 needs the ID from t2 and not the other way around, you should make the INSTEAD of trigger on t1 insert into t2 first, then t1. You can use the OUTPUT clause on the insert into t2.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot use OUTPUT clause on a remote table or view. So probably stored procedure is the only option.

Comment: So you are creating the sp to do the t2 insert on the server that t2 sits on, right? So you will still do the t2 insert first and use the id that comes back to do the t1 insert.

Comment: No, the current solution works like this: 1. insert into t1. 2. pack data into xml and insert into t2 with sp. 3. update t1

Answer (score 0):

Use a **Stored Procedure** and the **@@Identity** from the first insert.

Comment: Thanks for suggenstion, but @@identity will not solve the problem in case when muptiple values are inserted into table1.

Comment: Are you saying that Step 1: Insert into T1. Step 2: Insert Into T2. Step 3: Update t1 with T2.ID from step 2?

Comment: Yes, that was the starting idea

Comment: Is the data stored int T1.value unique? In your one row example you have "TEST". Is it possible that the value "TEST" could be inserted multiple times?

Comment: Do you mean, if there is an alternative unique key in the t1 except for primary key? No, I cannot garantee this

Answer (score 0):

What about just getting the max ID on the table?

```
DECLARE @SomethingID INT
SELECT @SomethingID = MAX(SomethingID) FROM SomethingTable
```

Comment: It's not safe because between the insert and select max(id) queries somebody could perform another insert operation and ruin the whole logic

Comment: Take a look at this question. It may help with regards to max problem: lock-a-few-tables-would-it-be-bad

Comment: Sorry, this is the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6460575/if-i-could-lock-a-few-tables-would-it-be-bad